# winrm or requests is not installed: No module named winrm

Tags: powershell, jenkins, ansible, winrm

I have a small simple setup consisting of Jenkins & Ansible 2.7.8 running on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (192.168.0.202):

```
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/home/jon/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

Jenkins ver. 2.150.3

I then have a Windows VM (192.168.0.203) that has a Powershell script stored on it and an Ansible playbook configured to connect to the Windows VM and run the Powershell script.

When I run the Ansible-Playbook directly from the command line it works fine, connects to the Windows machine and runs the script. All good.

I am having real trouble though implementing Ansible into Jenkins to run the playbook. When I run the playbook through Jenkins, I get the following error:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ansible-RunPS-1.0
[Ansible-RunPS-1.0] $ /usr/bin/ansible-playbook //etc/ansible/runPS.yml -f 5

PLAY [Runs remote PS script] ***************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
[0;31mfatal: [192.168.0.203]: FAILED! => {"msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named winrm"}[0m
```

To me, it seems to be running the playbook but then failing as it cannot find the winrm module. Could it be something to do with the account that Jenkins uses can't somehow find the winrm module, yet if I run the same command under my account, it finds it ok ?

Happy to post other configs etc. if that would help but thought I'd try and keep it as simple as possible to begin with.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider using [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for better readability.

Comment: Apologies, thanks for making it look neater.

Comment: Can you try to compare the env between manual execution and jenkins execution ? see if there is any difference in env variables, path etc.

Answer (score 0):

As is the way with these things, you spend days trying to fix it, then as soon as you ask for help you manage to fix it.
I'd love to be able to say it was just a case of installing this or running that but in truth, I really don't know what got it going, it suddenly burst into life after a reboot, can't believe that's all it was but you never know!